# Locally connected but not connected

Tags: general-topology

Problem : The subspace $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ of the real line $\mathbb{R}$ is locally connected but not connected.

I can see that the space is not connected since it can be written as a union of two disjoint non-empty open sets. I can also see that it is locally connected, but I am having trouble proving it. For the point, say $1$, how can I prove that for every open $V$ set containing it there exists a connected open set $U$ with $1 \in U \subset V$. It just seems like a lot of work. Is there a trick I am missing or I just don't understand the problem very well. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An open subset of $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ containing $1$ is the restriction of an open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $1$ and thus contains the restriction of an open interval containing $1$. This interval can be written as $(1-\epsilon,1+\epsilon)$ for some $\epsilon>0$. Restricting to $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ you get $(1-\epsilon,1]$, which is connected and open in $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$.

Answer (score 2):

If $1\in V$ and $V$ is open, then (assuming the standard topology on $\mathbb R$) there exists an interval $(a,b)$ with $1\in (a,b)\subseteq V$ (this follows from the definition of the subspace topology and the open sets in $\mathbb R$). But $(a,b)$ is connected.